# Laravel model returns error 404

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Model problem in Laravel 4.1

I have this model:

```
 class Blog extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'blog';
 }
```

And controller:

```
 public function index(){
    $posts = Blog::all(); 
    return View::make('blog/index')->with('posts', $posts);
 }
```

I already did  artisan dump-autoload, but I always get:

`error 404`

I did some tests with passing vars to the view and it's working, but not with Blog model. 
Really can't figure out why because everything by now seems correct.

Comment: You're getting a 404 error? Is it a Laravel 404 error or an Apache 404 error? If it's Laravel we'll need to see your routes as well.

Comment: Nginx error 404 error. Routes are fine.

Comment: Well if it's a 404 then the page cannot be found. What's that got to do with the model?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using View::make('blog.index') instead of View::make('blog/index') ?

Comment: your route is not working. next you should get a 500 internal server error.

Comment: The page can be found, i already have tested the template and the route, but when try to query blog table i get error 404

Comment: There is not enough details on this. Please provide more data. How about the Whoops stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Answer, name duplication in migration class.